# float_fast in C (similar to int_fast in stdint.h)

Tags: c, performance

I'm making a pong program and was simply wondering if there is a fast float in C. Bonus points for other data types like double.

P.S. I tried to look this up but to no avail.

Comment: Presuming this is for a PC-alike: What does make you think your pong will suffer from too low CPU perfomance where modern 3D Shooter do not?

Comment: @Olaf It's not really about the pong game, I was just wondering for future use.

Comment: Note that the 'fast' types in `<stdint.h>` are names such as `int_fast8_t`, the fastest integer type that is at least 8 bits wide.  There are only three standard floating point types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`.  There are no 'fast' names for floating point types in standard C.

Comment: `int` is typically the fastes integer type on platforms with at least 16 bit ALU. The `int_fastN_t` types are to guarantee a minimum bit-width. They are not necessarily the fastest integer type on your platform, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C standard language and library define no such type(s).

`<stdint.h>` defines `[u]int_fastN_t`, with `N` equal to 8, 16 32, and 64. Each such type is the "fastest" integer type of the given width. These are not special types that are faster than the built-in types. They are merely aliases for existing types, chosen for having the best performance. For example, 16-bit integers might be faster than 32-bit integers on one system, or slower on another.

There are exactly 3 standard floating-point types in C, `float`, `double`, and `long double`. The language provides no means of determining which of them is the fastest.

In practice, either `float` or `double` will most likely be the fastest floating-point type.  `float` is the smallest, and you might assume it's therefore the fastest, but in fact it depends on the current hardware. On some systems `double` might actually be faster than `float`. (I've never bothered to measure it myself.)

`double` is in a sense the "default" floating-point type. It is the type of an unsuffixed floating-point constant like `42.0`, and the functions in `<math.h>` show a bias for type `double`. For example, `sqrt()` operates on `double`, and `sqrtl()` and `sqrtl()` operate on `float` and `long double` respectively.

My advice: Use type `double`. If it turns out that your code isn't fast enough consider trying `float` instead -- and *measure* the actual performance on your system. Remember that your code doesn't have to be as fast as possible; it just has to be fast enough. It's not likely that floating-point speed is going to be a performance bottleneck for a pong program on a reasonably modern computer.

It's even possible that you could implement pong using only integer arithmetic, which is likely to be faster than floating-point -- but the difference is unlikely to be critical.

Comment: Keith, what an answer. Will definitely delete mine.